# amazon ec2 linux redhat server install unar package

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, redhat, yum, sudo

I'm just trying to install unar package for the purpose of uncompress compressed files. What I've tried is

```
sudo yum install unar
```

But it shows `"No package unar available"`.

I googled and downloaded a source file to build it. [This](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/unarchiver-finally-free-software-tool.html) is the link I found but it shows apt-get command. When I am trying this on my amazon server there is no command `"apt-get"`. So I tried this with `yum`. Again it shows no package available.

Even I tried this also

```
sudo yum install build-essential libgnustep-base-dev libz-dev libbz2-dev libssl-dev libicu-dev
```

But the same error `No package available` for all these packages.

So my question is how to install `unar` or `unarchiver` package on my `amazon ec2` server using `yum` command?

Someone help me please

Comment: @Downvoter.. reason please

Comment: I think the package is just called rar, then you use -u to unpack.

Comment: @Matías it is not rar.

Answer (score 2):

To see what package contains a command, you can use `sudo yum search unar`.  If you still can't find it, it may not be present in the repos you have enabled and you might need to enable additional repos or install that package manually or build it from source - just be sure any repos you add are trustworthy.

Comment: Ok. I ll try this